# Python Regex Partial Match or "hitEnd"

Tags: python, regex

I'm writing a scanner, so I'm matching an arbitrary string against a list of regex rules. It would be useful if I could emulate the Java "hitEnd" functionality of knowing not just when the regular expression didn't match, but when it **can't** match; when the regular expression matcher reached the end of the input before deciding it was rejected, indicating that a longer input might satisfy the rule.

For example, maybe I'm matching html tags for starting to bold a sentence of the form "< b >". So I compile my rule

```
bold_html_rule = re.compile("<b>")
```

And I run some tests:

```
good_match = bold_html_rule.match("<b>")
uncertain_match = bold_html_rule.match("<")
bad_match = bold_html_rule.match("goat")
```

How can I tell the difference between the "bad" match, for which *goat* can never be made valid by more input, and the ambiguous match that isn't a match yet, but could be.

**Attempts**

1. It is clear that in the above form, there is no way to distinguish, because both the uncertain attempt and the bad attempt return "None". If I wrap all rules in "(RULE)?" then any input will return a match, because at the least the empty string is a substring of all strings. However, when I try and see how far the regex progressed before rejecting my string by using the *group* method or *endPos* field, it is always just the length of the string.

Does the Python regex package do a lot of extra work and traverse the whole string even if it's an invalid match on the first character? I can see what it would have to if I used **search**, which will verify if the sequence is anywhere in the input, but it seems very strange to do so for **match**.

I've found the question asked before (on non-stackoverflow places) like this one:
https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2012-April/622358.html
but he doesn't really get a response.

I looked at the regular expression package itself but wasn't able to discern its behavior; could I extend the package to get this result? Is this the wrong way to tackle my task in the first place (I've built effective Java scanners using this strategy in the past)

Comment: Have you looked at the partial attribute in the regex package?

Comment: I can't find that, is it listed here https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html?

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: That does look more powerful, but I'm really asking if there's a way to it with the included module. I realize that the line about me writing my own package sort of contradicted that, so I just edited that out. I'll definitely give it a look though if the build-in module can't do it!

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you can't create conditionals/rules to handle these various scenarios, including a 'None'.  Perhaps provide more code showing an attempt to craft as much and why it isn't what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. It does feel like a hack, but at least it does achieve the result you are looking for. Though I am a bit concerned about the `PrepareCompileString` function. It should be able to handle all the `escaped characters`, but cannot handle any `wildcards`

```
import re

#Grouping every single character
def PrepareCompileString(regexString):
    newstring = ''
    escapeFlag = False
    for char in regexString:
        if escapeFlag:
            char = escapeString+char
            escapeFlag = False
            escapeString = ''
        if char == '\\':
            escapeFlag = True
            escapeString = char
        if not escapeFlag:
            newstring += '({})?'.format(char)
    return newstring

def CheckMatch(match):

    # counting the number of non matched groups
    count = match.groups().count(None)

    # If all groups matched - good match 
    # all groups did not match - bad match
    # few groups matched - uncertain match

    if count == 0:
        print('Good Match:', match.string)
    elif count < len(match.groups()):
        print('Uncertain Match:', match.string)
    elif count == len(match.groups()):
        print('Bad Match:', match.string)

regexString = '<b>'
bold_html_rule = re.compile(PrepareCompileString(regexString))

good_match = bold_html_rule.match("<b>")
uncertain_match = bold_html_rule.match("<")
bad_match = bold_html_rule.match("goat")

for match in [good_match, uncertain_match, bad_match]:
    CheckMatch(match)
```

I got this result:

```
Good Match: <b>
Uncertain Match: <
Bad Match: goat
```