# Python Regular expression potential match

Tags: python, regex

I'm using the re module to validate IP address, this is my pattern:

`"^\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$"`

Is there a way to know if a string ***can become*** a potential match without chaniging the pattern? for example: `"127.0.0."` is good or `"10.0"` however `"10.."` is not good. I don't mean the `re.match` function, I want to know if a string is not a match but it could be.

I need a function that will do something like this:

```
import re
p = re.potential("10.0","^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
print p # True
```

**Edit:** the thing is I want to know if I can recognize a potential match and use it to limit the wx.TextCtrl with the wx.EVT_CHAR Event, I didn't ask about my pattern. right now I have implemented it like this:

```
def OnChar(self,event):
    """event validation of ip"""
    key = event.GetKeyCode()
    text_value = event.GetEventObject().GetValue()
    length = len(text_value)
    numbers = True
    point = True

    if length:
        if length>2 and '.' not in text_value[-1:-4:-1]:
            numbers = False
        elif text_value[-1] =='.':
            point=False

    if Keys.is_numeric(key) and numbers:
        event.Skip()

    if Keys.equal(key,'.') and point:
        event.Skip()

    if Keys.is_moves(key):
        event.Skip()
```

This way the text the user enters can't be something not good, but is there a way to do it with the re module?

Comment: Check out the [Regex 101 website](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Note that you should use `\.` instead of `.` because it's a special character.

Comment: check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264005/using-a-regex-to-match-ip-addresses-in-python

Comment: I declared it as a raw string so it ignores all specials

Comment: `re.search` will show you potential matches if you want to stick to the command line.

Comment: Seriously, the link I sent. Your questions is more than answered there

Comment: It's a special regex character (like `^` and `$`), not an escape character (like `\ `). Check it with `127r0h0x0` and you'll see that it also passes

Comment: Sometimes using regex is overkill...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want an expression that matches when something can *become* an IP address, in a way. Just make parts optional:

```
^(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){0,2}(?:\.\d{0,3})?)?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yM2kJ0/1): This matches `12`, `234.54`, `23.53.12.5` and the empty string, but not `34.34..4` or `3546.34`.

**edit:** Less nested, thanks to Casimir et Hippolyte.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant. Is there a way to do it with Python or I need to modify all my regular expressions? I have also for mac address and more..

Comment: You can of course do this with python, just use my regex instead.

Comment: I meant without changing the pattern

Comment: …why do you not want to change the pattern? Without changing it, I don't believe you can do it. There's no distinction between a partial match and a non-match.

Comment: [Actually, there appears to be a way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25925157/1016216). I don't get why you would want to do that, though.

Comment: I am not well known with writing regex patterns, so I want to know if I can do this without changing all my regular expressions in my project

Comment: Move all your identical regexes in one place and use variables everywhere else. That way changing it is easy. For now you can search-and-replace it, I guess. Otherwise look at my previous answer. But now you'll have to change things in many places anyways.

Comment: @ori This is a good answer. If you don't want to change anything then why use regex at all? This is easy enough without regex.

Comment: For the particular case of an IP, you can write it too in "a less nested way": `^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){0,2}(?:\.\d{0,3})?$`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte good point! I just changed it to accept the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) as

```
>>> if re.match(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", "10.0") :
...     print "Matched"
... else:
...     print "Not Matched"
... 
Not Matched
>>> if re.match(r"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}", "127.0.0.0") :
...     print "Matched"
... else:
...     print "Not Matched"
... 
Matched
```

**Note** : The `re.match` function performs an entire search on the string, hence the anchors `^` and `$` are safely omitted

Comment: it printed Not Matched to me.

Comment: @ori Event  `127.0.0.` is not valid, The valid ip must be `127.0.0.0`. See the edited answer. Hope it is clear now

Comment: this is not what I need, look at the edit

Comment: @ori: what you want is a pattern that matches incomplete IP addresses. There are no functions that can return whether "a string can become a potential match".